# indexPath.row is returning null in tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

indexPath.row returns null in tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath

I thought it was supposed to return the row selected.

When i look at indexPath in the debugger it (corectly) returns: "2 indexes [0, 0]"

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well `null` *is* `0`.  The `row` property is type `int` -- perhaps you're mistakenly using it as an object or pointer.

You mention that you want the actual "row" that was selected.  If you mean you want the *cell* that was selected, here's how:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Note that if you somehow programmatically select a row that's not currently visible, this will return `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

`indexPath.section` tells you what section it's asking for.

`indexPath.row` tells you which row in that section it wants.

**Both start at 0.**

You want to do something like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {     // 1st section
    if (indexPath.row ==  0) return cell1;
    if (indexPath.row ==  1) return cell2;
    if (indexPath.row ==  2) return cell3;
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {     // 2nd section
    if (indexPath.row ==  0) return cell4;
    if (indexPath.row ==  1) return cell5;
    if (indexPath.row ==  2) return cell6;
}
return nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the PATH to the row selected, not the row (or cell) itself.

indexPath(0,0) is the first cell of the first section. Depending on your test you are running, this may be the correct result.